# Zend 2 redirect (bug or feature)?

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect, zend-framework2

Zend 2 seems to execute the "redirect()->toUrl()" not directly if it's called.

I have the following code:

```
public function onBootstrap(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e) {
    $em = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $em->attach(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'onDispatch'));
}

public function onDispatch(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e) {
    $auth = new \Auth\Model\AuthModel($this->sql, $this->config);

    if (!$auth->isLoggedin()) {
        $this->redirect()->toUrl('/auth?page=' . urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
        //return false;
    }
    parent::onDispatch($e);
}
```

So if I run the above code it does NOT redirect straight on the call. Zend seems to go first through the Controller Actions and Views and then it executes the redirect. But if I do a "return false;" after i call the "redirect" the redirect works as expected.

Any idea why zend handle the redirect that way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to return the response object from the [Redirect Plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#redirect-plugin)

```
return $this->redirect()->toUrl('/auth?page=' . urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```